# How to cross compile in linux

Tags: c, linux, compilation

I have a makefile and if I want to compile it for different compilers what changes do I need in my makefile? One I know is to change CC value that is my compiler. What other changes do I need? For example 
my here is my make file:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall

all: hello

hello: main.o factorial.o hello.o
    $(CC) main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) factorial.cpp

hello.o: hello.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) hello.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *o hello
```

What changes do I need it to compile it for an other processor?
And how to know the name of compiler linker arch etc. of the processor?

Comment: What cross compiler did you install?  Did it not come with documentation?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you are already using a compiler that can emit code for different targets, it is a question of setting the proper flags, e.g. imagine `CC=süper-cross-compiler` and `CFLAGS=eye-phone`.

If you must switch to another compiler which has compatible flags, you would have to to change your `$(CC)` variable and probably others, or possibly you set another alias in your shell environment.

There's a Linux port of the GCC windows port MinGW. Some distributions ship it as `mingw-gcc`; on them, you would `CC=mingw-gcc`.

In any case and in general, you have to tweak multiple stuffs. It all depends on the exact circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

In make define CC as

```
CC=$(CROSS)gcc
```

Invoke make like

```
CROSS=ppc_8xx- make
```

CROSS can be arm-linux-gnu- or whatever.